# How to query or compute historical gas usage by address?

Tags: gas, json-rpc, full-node

I'm trying to understand how services like fees.wtf calculate lifetime gas used by and address. Is there an JSON-RPC call or would I have to run a modified full node to index?

Similarly for top gas-guzzler contracts. Is there an easier way to query the gas spent on contract transactions for a specific contract?